# How to get access to a containerized postgresql database from outside / apps

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have been struggling to get connection to postgresql container from both localhost and from outside.

Here is the very nice demo which works as such very well as it is demonstrated at https://linuxhint.com/postgresql_docker/. And below is the docker-compose.yml by which the postgres:12.2 and pgadmin are containerized and run. And indeed after running the docker-compose.yml file (by docker-compose up -d) they work.

You can then go in your browser to http://localhost:8080/ and have the direct access (with given crendentials, i.e., admin@linuxhint.com, secret) to pgadmin and start operating on your postgres:12.2 installation on docker.

However my difficulties start when I try to find get connection to this postgres:12.2 -database directly from localhost or outside/some application/ip (like Java Spring Boot).

Admittedly I am not an expert with docker, just the student - so, I asking for help. Hopefully someone can show me what should be done to make connection possible to (this) containerized postgres database from outside/app. I am using Win 10.

UPDATE:

- Can anyone say why a web-app (added below to docker.compose.yml, see below) is shutting down persistently after its launching?
- docker logs  gives the following error:

  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
- here is **Dockerfile** for the app:

  FROM  maven:3-jdk-11

  VOLUME /tmp

  EXPOSE 8095

  ADD /target/spring-boot-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

  RUN ls -ls

  ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
- and here is connection details in the **application.properties** file:

  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres

  spring.datasource.username=admin

  spring.datasource.password=secret
- two other servies (db and pgadmin starts normally)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:

# ========== ADDED APP ===============
 web:
   #restart: on-failure
   image: app-springboot-postgresql
   build: ./
   ports:
     - "8095:8095"
   environment:
     WAIT_HOSTS: postgres:5432
   depends_on:
    - db  
# ========== ADDED APP ===============

  db:
    image: postgres:12.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
 
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@linuxhint.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    links:
      - "db:pgsql-server"

volumes:
  db-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

Comment: Can't you connect with container name?

Comment: Only means I have been able to connect to containerized postgresql (as defined above in the yml-file) has been: "docker-compose run db bash". And then:  "psql -h db -U admin -d postgres" and "Password for user admin: secret".

Comment: from the error: `Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5433 refused.` you have the postgresql configured on 5433 and from yaml you start that on 5432

Comment: Edwin, you are right, there is inconsistency between the error message and the code. That error was related to some the strange memory update error I reported about in my comment below. Thank you for your sharp observation.

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose.yml` publishes port 5432 of Postgres to machine where docker daemon runs.

So applications should connect to `127.0.0.1` as Postgres host and `5432` as Postgres port assuming they run on the machine.

Comment: By this I can connect from localhost: psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres, BUT connection does not go to app in containerized postgresql (i.e the one defined in yml-file above) but instead it open up the connection to local uncontainerized postgresql.

Comment: if you successfully ran `docker-compose up` command in the folder where `docker-compose.yml` file is located, containerized Postgres port 5432 of containerized Postgres is mapped to port 5432 of docker host (machine where you docker daemon runs) and when you run `psql` the way you published you connect to containerized Postgres

Comment: I can run "docker-compose up" (in the same folder) with success and if I then run "psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres", I only get connection to my non-containerized database (with fully different databases and tables from the one that are in the containerized one). And if change the username to admin and use the corresponding password (these are the credentials given in the docker-compose.yml file) and when I run psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U admin) then comes the password-prompt and I get the error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin".

Comment: If you're running a separate PostgreSQL on your host, you need to change the published `ports:`; change only the first number to some different port, like `5433:5432`.  But I'd expect you to have problems starting up if there's a host-port conflict.  Are you running Docker Toolbox or Docker Desktop?

Comment: How can I know if I am running Docker Toolbox or Docker Desktop?

Comment: Yes David, the port change helped and I was now capable of connecting from outside to containerized postgre-database. So, there was the port conflict obviously, as you suggested. So, at least partly the issue is now solved. I leave this open still for a while, because I may need to ask yet something more.

Comment: I have now a further question related to connection issue, see above my original question I have updated it with new question

Comment: please, ask a new question as asking numerous questions in one post is against the rules.

"This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Comment: rok, sorry for any inconvenience due to my ignorance of posting new question in on post. I will do better in future.

Comment: I found strange reason for my issue - after couple of hours of getting same error given above, I decided, in the face of absurdity, to reboot my pc and to start docker and ide again. And, surprisingly, I started to get a fully different error from spring app (unrelated to connections and ports) which made sense and fixed it. Then the container for the spring boot app kept on running and I was then also capable of getting all services work together as expected. Sometimes even logical things behave oddly. Anyway I got also help from many of you, and learned something new of docker, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check if they are in the same network:

```
docker network ls

# Output

NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
e094bb99be32        bridge              bridge              local
cde9fb0d3fef        django              bridge              local
1aeb83753889        host                host                local
f152a346ca96        none                null                local
348c59c37462        web                 bridge              local
```

Then inspect the network:

```
docker network inspect django

# Output

[
    {
        "Name": "django",
        "Id": "6f5fd395946d1bff8583a4ddbe4fb8ea1204875124679f878d24a57f3601b0e6",
        "Created": "2020-10-11T13:16:42.750571609+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "079d303b3c2d17196e7cb49056ec7cfc7385c480c3cbf225dc51e53ebeb43f10": {
                "Name": "pgadmin",
                "EndpointID": "10e1f181f18e751ce0b3521f537e30948433e62b454fb9707b96333395f5ba36",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "bff75ff8e23ab998cfc99bc87bec05ea9fb55adbcae1993da1cbc719eea90fd3": {
                "Name": "postgres",
                "EndpointID": "edd547148b50c6c3319f2b65ec151816e14f9ea9e7dd9acb9b5895d44fcd6cda",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

In the example above postgres and pgadmin are in the same network, so they see each other.

If in you case they are not in the same network, define it explicitly.

```
# docker-compose.yml

services:
  django:
    container_name: dj
    build:
      context: ./server
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/staticfiles
      - mediafiles:/app/media
    command: gunicorn nohchi_mott.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file: ./server/.env
    expose:
      - 8000
    networks:
      - web
      - django
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    expose:
      - 5432
    networks:
      - django
    env_file: ./db/.env
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    env_file: ./db/pgadmin/.env
    links:
      - db:pgsql-server
    networks:
      - web
      - django
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  staticfiles:
  mediafiles:
  postgres_data:
  pgadmin_data:

networks:
  web:
    external: true
  django:
    external: false
```